# how to use "snapshot.hasData" with Dynamic Future builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, dynamic-function

I had a String type future method but I had to do some modifications to the code and I changed my future method to dynamic future and everysince the future builder never validate if snapshot has data

```
  late final Future myFuture;

 @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture =  getUserInfo();

    super.initState();
  }

Future  getUserInfo() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool check = preferences.containsKey('$userID,imageURL');
    if(check == true){
      userName = preferences.getString('$userID,name')?? "No name found";
      userWeight = preferences.getString('$userID,weight') ?? "no wight found";
      userHeight = preferences.getString('$userID,height') ?? "no Height found";
      userGender = preferences.getString('$userID,genderType') ?? "no gender Type found";
      birthDateInString = preferences.getString('$userID,dateOfBirth') ?? "no date  found";
      imageURL = preferences.getString('$userID,imageURL') ?? "no image  found";
    }else{
      await downloadValues();
    }


  }

..........

 Widget userValues(){
    return
      FutureBuilder(
        future: myFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );
            }
            else if (snapshot.hasData){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(

                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("$userName",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: GoogleFonts.mouseMemoirs(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.black
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              );
            }
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
  }
```

In this case the future builder is always returning CircularProgressIndicator. However, if I change the condition from **else if (snapshot.hasData)** to just else {   }, then the code will run properly but I dont think thats how it should be done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `getUserInfo()` never returns anything, that's why `snapshot.hasData` is always `false`

Comment: @pskink ya I will add a return to the method and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pskink is right. You should return a value (if you're using the returned value) or return nothing (like: `return;`) and set another value somewhere else and use this, which you are doing right now if I understood correctly.

Edit: my mistake. `snapshot.hasData` checks if anything returned from the future. You should return a value from the Future in this case. Sorry about that.

```dart
Future  getUserInfo() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool check = preferences.containsKey('$userID,imageURL');
    if(check == true){
      userName = preferences.getString('$userID,name')?? "No name found";
      userWeight = preferences.getString('$userID,weight') ?? "no wight found";
      userHeight = preferences.getString('$userID,height') ?? "no Height found";
      userGender = preferences.getString('$userID,genderType') ?? "no gender Type found";
      birthDateInString = preferences.getString('$userID,dateOfBirth') ?? "no date  found";
      imageURL = preferences.getString('$userID,imageURL') ?? "no image  found";
    }else{
      await downloadValues();
    }

   return userName; // this should do the trick
  }
```

Comment: Thanks KHAN for your answer. I actually tried that before (return userName) and it was working fine but I thought to my self that this might not be optimal but I think I will go back to it. Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: Well.. didn't see that coming :) In that case, you may want to try some other options: You can create a model for that values, I'm assuming it's a user, so a `User` class to encompass all these values and assigning values to an object (created from `User` class) and returning this should work tremendously. This option is far more readable and has more meaning inside.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, I belive I should do what you said since I am also using these values on different classes and I am doing the same process over and over everytime I need to use these values on different screens. Thanks for your suggestion and help, I appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could be a help. And it's awesome for you to be aware of the possible issues with rewriting the same code over and look for a better option! Good luck with that also :)